# Django Serializer - Support Multiple Field Types

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want my serializer to support multiple types of serialized lists. For example, in the BundleSerializer below, I want the identifier to support two or more types of identifiers, that can be a list of IdentifierSerializer objects.

```py
class BundleModel(models.Model):
    fullUrl = FHIR_DATATYPE_URI()

# IdentifierSerializerA and IdentifierSerializerB has two different models and corresponding serializers

class BundleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    identifier = IdentifierSerializerA(many=True, required=False) || IdentifierSerializerB(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = BundleModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

How can I make this work? Also, the `identifier` property can host a list of both type of objects from `IdentifierSerializerA` and `IdentifierSerializerB`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SerializerMethodField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) for this kind of purpose. For example:

```
class BundleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    identifier_data = serializer.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = BundleModel
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_identifier_data(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj.identifier, IdentifierA):
           return IdentifierSerializerA(obj.identifier)
        return  IdentifierSerializerB(obj.identifier)
```